# Pop! OS - Add custom shortcuts to app launcher

Tags: ubuntu, pop-os

In Pop! OS, the app launcher looks similar to [ulauncher](https://ulauncher.io/). ulauncher allows me to define shortcuts for search queries which is super handy and i use it all the time.

For example, i want to define a shortcut like this:
keyword: g
query: https://google.de/search?q=%S

And enter this in the app launcher:
g search term

Is there a way to define shortcuts like this in the native Pop! OS app launcher?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is simply not implemented in GNOME runner as far as I see. Krunner, the Plasma counterpart has this feature though. You can use search provider extentions like the [Google one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4132/google-search-provider/), [youtube one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1457/youtube-search-provider/) and so on which will add search suggestions from them.

Answer (score 2):

Google already in pop! OS lanucher. use `gs` in front of your query.

Check out `/usr/lib/pop-launcher/plugins/web/config.ron` file.
You can change or add shoutcuts by changing that file.

---

You can also create new plugin easily by changing existing one.
https://www.arm64.ca/post/creating-launch-plugins-for-pop-os/

Comment: It would be good to [edit] and  include the basic relevant details from the link. If/when the link dies, then your answer may not be as usefulo as it could have been.